# QStringList split() function and simplifyWhiteSpace() function

Tags: qt, split, qt5, qstringlist

I am using Qt5 and errors exist from this line of codes after running sample project I found on the internet.

> QFile f( "world.txt" );
>
> ```
>     if( f.open( QIODevice::ReadOnly ) )       {           
>        QTextStream ts( &f );
>        Vertex v[3];           
>        int vcount = 0;             
>        bool allok, ok;
>       while( !ts.atEnd() )
>         {
>
>             QStringList line = QString::split( " ",ts.readLine().simplifyWhiteSpace() );
> ```

Errors are:

> ```
> split is not a member of QStringList
> simplifyWhiteSpace is not a member of QString
> ```

I don't know how to convert the line to work on Qt5.

Comment: 1. QStringList::split: change `QStringList::split(` to`QString::split(`, 2. SimplifyWhiteSpace() I can not find either in C ++ or Qt, so you probably have an outdated example, check with the author of the code.

Comment: I have edited and include some codes if it confuse you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `QStringList::split()` and `QString::simplifyWhitespace()` were functions in Qt3, and have been renamed or moved for Qt5 (which you are using according to your tags).

For `QStringList::split()`, the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qstringlist-qt3.html) says:

> Use QString::split(sep, QString::SkipEmptyParts) or QString::split(sep, QString::KeepEmptyParts) instead.
>
> Be aware that the QString::split()'s return value is a QStringList that always contains at least one element, even if str is empty.

You already changed this in your edit, so you are left with `QString::simplifyWhitespace()`, where the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qstring-qt3.html) says:

> QString QString::simplifyWhiteSpace () const
>
> Use [`simplified()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#simplified) instead.

Comment: may I ask for the exact syntax for this?